# Why do clang++ and clang-check produce different ASTs?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to analyze clang's AST coming from this small code snippet.

```
struct Foo {
  Foo() = default;
  Foo(int num) : i(num) {}
  Foo(Foo &&other) {
    i = other.i;
    other.i = 0;
  }

  int i = 0;
};

Foo createAElidable(int i);

void func() { Foo foo = createAElidable(1234); }

Foo createAElidable(int i) { return Foo(i); }
```

Runnning "clang++ -Xclang -ast-dump example.cpp" gives me this output:

```
TranslationUnitDecl #1 0x55c2ba1c07d8 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc>
|-TypedefDecl #2 0x55c2ba1c10e0 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit
| `-BuiltinType 0x55c2ba1c0d80 '__int128'
|-TypedefDecl #3 0x55c2ba1c1158 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit
| `-BuiltinType 0x55c2ba1c0da0 'unsigned __int128'
|-TypedefDecl #9 0x55c2ba1c14f8 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit
| `-RecordType 0x55c2ba1c1250 '__NSConstantString_tag'
|   `-CXXRecord 0x55c2ba1c11b8 '__NSConstantString_tag'
|-TypedefDecl #10 0x55c2ba1c15a0 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit
| `-PointerType 0x55c2ba1c1560 'char *'
|   `-BuiltinType 0x55c2ba1c0880 'char'
|-TypedefDecl #16 0x55c2ba202118 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit
| `-ConstantArrayType 0x55c2ba2020c0 '__va_list_tag [1]' 1
|   `-RecordType 0x55c2ba1c16a0 '__va_list_tag'
|     `-CXXRecord 0x55c2ba1c1600 '__va_list_tag'
|-CXXRecordDecl #17 0x55c2ba202178 <test27_copy_elision2.cpp:1:1, line:10:1> line:1:8 referenced
| |-CXXRecordDecl #18 0x55c2ba202298 <col:1, col:8> col:8 implicit referenced
| |-CXXConstructorDecl #19 0x55c2ba2023b8 <line:2:3, col:17> col:3 constexpr
| |-CXXConstructorDecl #21 0x55c2ba202548 <line:3:3, col:26> col:3 used
| | |-ParmVarDecl #20 0x55c2ba202480 <col:7, col:11> col:11 used
| | |-CXXCtorInitializer Field 0x55c2ba2027d8 'i' 'int'
| | | `-ImplicitCastExpr #32 0x55c2ba202c68 <col:20> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
| | |   `-DeclRefExpr #30 0x55c2ba202c18 <col:20> 'int' lvalue ParmVar 0x55c2ba202480 'num' 'int'
| | `-CompoundStmt 0x55c2ba202cb8 <col:25, col:26>
| |-CXXConstructorDecl #23 0x55c2ba202708 <line:4:3, line:7:3> line:4:3 used
| | |-ParmVarDecl #22 0x55c2ba202638 <col:7, col:13> col:13 used
| | |-CXXCtorInitializer Field 0x55c2ba2027d8 'i' 'int'
| | | `-CXXDefaultInitExpr #33 0x55c2ba202cc8 <col:3> 'int'
| | `-CompoundStmt 0x55c2ba202f18 <col:20, line:7:3>
| |   |-BinaryOperator #40 0x55c2ba202e40 <line:5:5, col:15> 'int' lvalue '='
| |   | |-MemberExpr #36 0x55c2ba202d88 <col:5> 'int' lvalue ->i 0x55c2ba2027d8
| |   | | `-CXXThisExpr #35 0x55c2ba202d70 <col:5> 'Foo *' implicit this
| |   | `-ImplicitCastExpr #39 0x55c2ba202e20 <col:9, col:15> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
| |   |   `-MemberExpr #38 0x55c2ba202de8 <col:9, col:15> 'int' lvalue .i 0x55c2ba2027d8
| |   |     `-DeclRefExpr #37 0x55c2ba202dc0 <col:9> 'Foo' lvalue ParmVar 0x55c2ba202638 'other' 'Foo &&'
| |   `-BinaryOperator #44 0x55c2ba202ef0 <line:6:5, col:15> 'int' lvalue '='
| |     |-MemberExpr #42 0x55c2ba202e90 <col:5, col:11> 'int' lvalue .i 0x55c2ba2027d8
| |     | `-DeclRefExpr #41 0x55c2ba202e68 <col:5> 'Foo' lvalue ParmVar 0x55c2ba202638 'other' 'Foo &&'
| |     `-IntegerLiteral #43 0x55c2ba202ec8 <col:15> 'int' 0
| |-FieldDecl #24 0x55c2ba2027d8 <line:9:3, col:11> col:7 referenced
| | `-IntegerLiteral #29 0x55c2ba202bf0 <col:11> 'int' 0
| |-CXXConstructorDecl #25 0x55c2ba202858 <line:1:8> col:8 implicit constexpr
| | `-ParmVarDecl #26 0x55c2ba202978 <col:8> col:8
| |-CXXMethodDecl #27 0x55c2ba202a18 <col:8> col:8 implicit
| | `-ParmVarDecl #28 0x55c2ba202b28 <col:8> col:8
| `-CXXDestructorDecl #55 0x55c2ba2313a8 <col:8> col:8 implicit referenced
|-FunctionDecl #46 0x55c2ba231048 <line:12:1, col:26> col:5 used
| `-ParmVarDecl #45 0x55c2ba230f80 <col:21, col:25> col:25
|-FunctionDecl #48 0x55c2ba231168 <line:14:1, col:48> col:6
| `-CompoundStmt 0x55c2ba231548 <col:13, col:48>
|   `-DeclStmt 0x55c2ba231530 <col:15, col:46>
|     `-VarDecl #49 0x55c2ba231220 <col:15, col:45> col:19
|       `-ExprWithCleanups #58 0x55c2ba231510 <col:25, col:45> 'Foo'
|         `-CXXConstructExpr #57 0x55c2ba2314d8 <col:25, col:45> 'Foo' 'void (Foo &&)' elidable
|           `-MaterializeTemporaryExpr #56 0x55c2ba2314b8 <col:25, col:45> 'Foo' xvalue
|             `-CallExpr #54 0x55c2ba231378 <col:25, col:45> 'Foo'
|               |-ImplicitCastExpr #53 0x55c2ba231358 <col:25> 'Foo (*)(int)' <FunctionToPointerDecay>
|               | `-DeclRefExpr #52 0x55c2ba231308 <col:25> 'Foo (int)' lvalue Function 0x55c2ba231048 'createAElidable' 'Foo (int)'
|               `-IntegerLiteral #51 0x55c2ba2312e0 <col:41> 'int' 1234
`-FunctionDecl #60 0x55c2ba231610 prev 0x55c2ba231048 <line:16:1, col:45> col:5 used
  |-ParmVarDecl #59 0x55c2ba231578 <col:21, col:25> col:25 used
  `-CompoundStmt 0x55c2ba231808 <col:28, col:45>
    `-ReturnStmt 0x55c2ba2317f8 <col:30, col:42>
      `-ExprWithCleanups #67 0x55c2ba2317d8 <col:37, col:42> 'Foo'
        `-CXXConstructExpr #66 0x55c2ba2317a0 <col:37, col:42> 'Foo' 'void (Foo &&)' elidable
          `-MaterializeTemporaryExpr #65 0x55c2ba231780 <col:37, col:42> 'Foo' xvalue
            `-CXXFunctionalCastExpr #64 0x55c2ba231750 <col:37, col:42> 'Foo' functional cast to struct Foo <ConstructorConversion>
              `-CXXConstructExpr #63 0x55c2ba231718 <col:37, col:42> 'Foo' 'void (int)'
                `-ImplicitCastExpr #62 0x55c2ba2316f8 <col:41> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
                  `-DeclRefExpr #61 0x55c2ba2316d0 <col:41> 'int' lvalue ParmVar 0x55c2ba231578 'i' 'int'
```

So far so good.

Clang's source also comes with examples for their refactoring api. One is called clang-check and also provides an AST dump.

"clang-check --ast-dump" produces:

```
TranslationUnitDecl #1 0x563d3b96bfa8 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc>
|-TypedefDecl #2 0x563d3b96c8b0 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit
| `-BuiltinType 0x563d3b96c550 '__int128'
|-TypedefDecl #3 0x563d3b96c928 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit
| `-BuiltinType 0x563d3b96c570 'unsigned __int128'
|-TypedefDecl #9 0x563d3b96ccc8 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit
| `-RecordType 0x563d3b96ca20 '__NSConstantString_tag'
|   `-CXXRecord 0x563d3b96c988 '__NSConstantString_tag'
|-TypedefDecl #10 0x563d3b96cd70 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit
| `-PointerType 0x563d3b96cd30 'char *'
|   `-BuiltinType 0x563d3b96c050 'char'
|-TypedefDecl #16 0x563d3b9ac468 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit
| `-ConstantArrayType 0x563d3b9ac410 '__va_list_tag [1]' 1
|   `-RecordType 0x563d3b96ce70 '__va_list_tag'
|     `-CXXRecord 0x563d3b96cdd0 '__va_list_tag'
|-CXXRecordDecl #17 0x563d3b9ac4c8 </home/tyrdal/projects/emx-llvm/worktrees/mo_clang_12/test_clang_ccode/test27_copy_elision2.cpp:1:1, line:10:1> line:1:8 referenced
| |-CXXRecordDecl #18 0x563d3b9ac5e8 <col:1, col:8> col:8 implicit referenced
| |-CXXConstructorDecl #19 0x563d3b9ac708 <line:2:3, col:17> col:3 constexpr
| |-CXXConstructorDecl #21 0x563d3b9ac898 <line:3:3, col:26> col:3 used
| | |-ParmVarDecl #20 0x563d3b9ac7d0 <col:7, col:11> col:11 used
| | |-CXXCtorInitializer Field 0x563d3b9acb28 'i' 'int'
| | | `-ImplicitCastExpr #32 0x563d3b9acfb8 <col:20> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
| | |   `-DeclRefExpr #30 0x563d3b9acf68 <col:20> 'int' lvalue ParmVar 0x563d3b9ac7d0 'num' 'int'
| | `-CompoundStmt 0x563d3b9ad008 <col:25, col:26>
| |-CXXConstructorDecl #23 0x563d3b9aca58 <line:4:3, line:7:3> line:4:3
| | |-ParmVarDecl #22 0x563d3b9ac988 <col:7, col:13> col:13 used
| | |-CXXCtorInitializer Field 0x563d3b9acb28 'i' 'int'
| | | `-CXXDefaultInitExpr #33 0x563d3b9ad018 <col:3> 'int'
| | `-CompoundStmt 0x563d3b9ad268 <col:20, line:7:3>
| |   |-BinaryOperator #40 0x563d3b9ad190 <line:5:5, col:15> 'int' lvalue '='
| |   | |-MemberExpr #36 0x563d3b9ad0d8 <col:5> 'int' lvalue ->i 0x563d3b9acb28
| |   | | `-CXXThisExpr #35 0x563d3b9ad0c0 <col:5> 'Foo *' implicit this
| |   | `-ImplicitCastExpr #39 0x563d3b9ad170 <col:9, col:15> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
| |   |   `-MemberExpr #38 0x563d3b9ad138 <col:9, col:15> 'int' lvalue .i 0x563d3b9acb28
| |   |     `-DeclRefExpr #37 0x563d3b9ad110 <col:9> 'Foo' lvalue ParmVar 0x563d3b9ac988 'other' 'Foo &&'
| |   `-BinaryOperator #44 0x563d3b9ad240 <line:6:5, col:15> 'int' lvalue '='
| |     |-MemberExpr #42 0x563d3b9ad1e0 <col:5, col:11> 'int' lvalue .i 0x563d3b9acb28
| |     | `-DeclRefExpr #41 0x563d3b9ad1b8 <col:5> 'Foo' lvalue ParmVar 0x563d3b9ac988 'other' 'Foo &&'
| |     `-IntegerLiteral #43 0x563d3b9ad218 <col:15> 'int' 0
| |-FieldDecl #24 0x563d3b9acb28 <line:9:3, col:11> col:7 referenced
| | `-IntegerLiteral #29 0x563d3b9acf40 <col:11> 'int' 0
| |-CXXConstructorDecl #25 0x563d3b9acba8 <line:1:8> col:8 implicit constexpr
| | `-ParmVarDecl #26 0x563d3b9accc8 <col:8> col:8
| |-CXXMethodDecl #27 0x563d3b9acd68 <col:8> col:8 implicit
| | `-ParmVarDecl #28 0x563d3b9ace78 <col:8> col:8
| `-CXXDestructorDecl #55 0x563d3b9dd3a8 <col:8> col:8 implicit referenced
|-FunctionDecl #46 0x563d3b9dd048 <line:12:1, col:26> col:5 used
| `-ParmVarDecl #45 0x563d3b9dcf80 <col:21, col:25> col:25
|-FunctionDecl #48 0x563d3b9dd168 <line:14:1, col:48> col:6
| `-CompoundStmt 0x563d3b9dd4d0 <col:13, col:48>
|   `-DeclStmt 0x563d3b9dd4b8 <col:15, col:46>
|     `-VarDecl #49 0x563d3b9dd220 <col:15, col:45> col:19
|       `-CallExpr #54 0x563d3b9dd378 <col:25, col:45> 'Foo'
|         |-ImplicitCastExpr #53 0x563d3b9dd358 <col:25> 'Foo (*)(int)' <FunctionToPointerDecay>
|         | `-DeclRefExpr #52 0x563d3b9dd308 <col:25> 'Foo (int)' lvalue Function 0x563d3b9dd048 'createAElidable' 'Foo (int)'
|         `-IntegerLiteral #51 0x563d3b9dd2e0 <col:41> 'int' 1234
`-FunctionDecl #57 0x563d3b9dd598 prev 0x563d3b9dd048 <line:16:1, col:45> col:5 used
  |-ParmVarDecl #56 0x563d3b9dd500 <col:21, col:25> col:25 used
  `-CompoundStmt 0x563d3b9dd718 <col:28, col:45>
    `-ReturnStmt 0x563d3b9dd708 <col:30, col:42>
      `-CXXFunctionalCastExpr #61 0x563d3b9dd6d8 <col:37, col:42> 'Foo' functional cast to struct Foo <ConstructorConversion>
        `-CXXConstructExpr #60 0x563d3b9dd6a0 <col:37, col:42> 'Foo' 'void (int)'
          `-ImplicitCastExpr #59 0x563d3b9dd680 <col:41> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
            `-DeclRefExpr #58 0x563d3b9dd658 <col:41> 'int' lvalue ParmVar 0x563d3b9dd500 'i' 'int'
```

As you can see, ther are no MaterializeTemporaraExpr Nodes in this version.Why are the two tools producing different ASTs? Am I missing some option?

I tried with (self compiles) version 10.0.1 and 12.0.0. Same behaviour in both cases.

PS: This only happens under Linux. I now tried under Win10 and here both tools generate the same output.

Comment: my guess would be that `clang-check` is just showing you the result of parsing the file whereas `clang++` has added constructor calls for temporary `Foo` objects.

Comment: Looks the clang-check is doing the literal AST of the written code. While clang AST has some additions. The compiler is allowed to add stuff to the code. From the top of my head, compiler generated methods (Copy Constructor/Assignment, Move Constructor/Assignment and destructor can all be generated by the compiler if not explicitly defined by the engineer). Also the compiler is allowed to perform a bunch of optimizations that could alter the AST to a degree (Loop removal/ Code hoisting/ dead code removal Copy elision)

Comment: The internal ast representation of compiler and what its analysis plugin utilities provide evolve somewhat separately from each other.  It is since only developer who wants to see what compiler is doing uses -ast-dump while several tools depend on output of refactoring api.

Comment: Ok, might be that clang is already doin more than just parsing. But is there a way to generate the same output from the refactoring api? That would be important to me.

Comment: Note that you fail to elaborate why it is important to you.